# Tkinter - export attachment

Tags: python, tkinter, pickle, autofill

So I have created a user form with Tkinter that has a button that allows you to attach the folder path of a file. The problem is I want to press a button to get the folder path instead of opening the file dialog right away. I have not found a way to save the "filePath" variable from the "openFile" function after the button is pressed.

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image  
import time
import pyautogui as py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk,Label, messagebox, font, filedialog
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import pickle
import json

# Create user form
root = Tk()
root.title('ServiceNow Access Request User Form')
root.configure(bg="#f6f6f8")
root.geometry("500x470")

# Combo & List box items
personnelStatus = ["-- None --","Regular Employee","Temporary Employee","Non Employee"]
requestType = ["-- None --","Access Change","Hire","ID Renewal"]
employeeType = ["-- None --","Contractor","Consultant","Vendor","Volunteer"]
accessChange = ["Active Directory", "Financial Systems"]

# Format
bigFont = font.Font(family='Microsoft Sans Serif',size= 12)
root.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Font", bigFont)

# AR Image
image = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\E100676\\Pictures\\AccessRequest.png")
label = tk.Label(root,image=image, bg="#f6f6f8")
label.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="w")

# Personnel status combo box (PS)
PSlabel = Label(root, text="    Personnel Status", bg="#f6f6f8", font= bigFont)
PSlabel.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="e")
PScombo = ttk.Combobox(root, value= personnelStatus, state='readonly', font= bigFont, width = 17)
PScombo.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="w")

# Request type combo box (RT)
RTlabel = Label(root, text="    Request Type", bg="#f6f6f8", font= bigFont)
RTlabel.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky="e")
RTcombo = ttk.Combobox(root, value= requestType, state='readonly', font= bigFont, width = 17)
RTcombo.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky="w")

# Employee Name text box (EN)
ENlabel = Label(root, text="    Employee Name", bg="#f6f6f8", font= bigFont)
ENlabel.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky="e")
ENentry = Entry(root, font= bigFont, width= 19)
ENentry.grid(column=1,row=4, sticky="w")

# Employee ID text box (EID)
EIDlabel = Label(root, text="    Employee ID", bg="#f6f6f8", font= bigFont)
EIDlabel.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky="e")
EIDentry = Entry(root, font= bigFont, width= 19)
EIDentry.grid(column=1,row=5, sticky="w")

# Employee Type combo box (ET)
ETlabel = Label(root, text="    Employee Type", bg="#f6f6f8", font= bigFont)
ETlabel.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky="e")
ETcombo = ttk.Combobox(root, value= employeeType, state='readonly', font= bigFont, width = 17)
ETcombo.grid(column=1, row=6, sticky="w")

# Organization Name text box (ON)
ONlabel = Label(root, text="    Organization Name", bg="#f6f6f8", font= bigFont)
ONlabel.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky="e")
ONentry = Entry(root, font= bigFont, width= 19)
ONentry.grid(column=1,row=7, sticky="w")

# Requested For text box (RF)
RFlabel = Label(root, text="    Requested For", bg="#f6f6f8", font= bigFont)
RFlabel.grid(column=0, row=8, sticky="e")
RFentry = Entry(root, font= bigFont, width= 19)
RFentry.grid(column=1,row=8, sticky="w")

# email text box (EM)
EMlabel = Label(root, text="    Email", bg="#f6f6f8", font= bigFont)
EMlabel.grid(column=0, row=9, sticky="e")
EMentry = Entry(root, font= bigFont, width= 19)
EMentry.grid(column=1,row=9, sticky="w")

# Access Change list box (AC)
AClabel = Label(root, text="    Access Change", bg="#f6f6f8", font= bigFont)
AClabel.grid(column=0, row=10, sticky="e")
AClist = Listbox(root, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE, height= 2, font= bigFont, width= 19)
for item in accessChange:
    AClist.insert(tk.END, item)
AClist.grid(column=1, row=10, sticky="w")

# COSD ID text box (EN)
cosdIDlabel = Label(root, text="    CoSD ID", bg="#f6f6f8", font= bigFont)
cosdIDlabel.grid(column=0, row=11, sticky="e")
cosdIDentry = Entry(root, font= bigFont, width= 19)
cosdIDentry.grid(column=1,row=11, sticky="w")

# Supp F file
def openFile():
    global filePath
    filePath = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a file")
    if filePath:
        fileLabel.config(text=filePath)
        return filePath

imagePath = "C:\\Users\\E100676\\Pictures\\attach-button.png"
img = PhotoImage(file= imagePath)

fileButton = Button(root, image= img, command=openFile, bg="#f6f6f8", font= bigFont)
fileButton.grid(column=0,row=12, sticky="e")

fileLabel = Label(root, text="No file attached", bg="#f6f6f8", font= bigFont)
fileLabel.grid(column=1,row=12, sticky="w")


# Retrieve selections
def PSfunction(event):
    global PSselection
    PSselection = PScombo.get()

def RTfunction(event):
    global RTselection
    RTselection = RTcombo.get()

def ENfunction(event):
    global ENentry
    ENentry = ENentry.get()

def EIDfunction(event):
    global EIDentry
    EIDentry = EIDentry.get()

def ETfunction(event):
    global ETselection
    ETselection = ETcombo.get()

def ONfunction(event):
    global ONentry
    ONentry = ONentry.get()

def RFfunction(event):
    global RFentry
    RFentry = RFentry.get()

def EMfunction(event):
    global EMentry
    EMentry = EMentry.get()

def ACfunction(event):
    global ACselection
    selected = AClist.curselection()
    ACselection = [AClist.get(index) for index in selected]

def cosdIDfunction(event):
    global cosdIDentry
    cosdIDentry = cosdIDentry.get()

def FLfunction(event):
    global fileLabel
    fileLabel = fileLabel.get()
  
# Bind selection
PScombo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", PSfunction)
RTcombo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", RTfunction)
ENentry.bind("<FocusOut>", ENfunction)
EIDentry.bind("<FocusOut>", EIDfunction)
ETcombo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", ETfunction)
ONentry.bind("<FocusOut>",ONfunction)
RFentry.bind("<FocusOut>", RFfunction)
EMentry.bind("<FocusOut>", EMfunction)
AClist.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", ACfunction)
cosdIDentry.bind("<FocusOut>", cosdIDfunction)
fileButton.bind("<Button-1>", FLfunction)


print(fileLabel)

# Create AutoFill Button
data = {
    'PersonnelStatus': '',
    'RequestType': '',
    'EmployeeName':'',
    'EmployeeID':'',
    'EmployeeType':'',
    'OrganizationName':'',
    'RequestedFor':'',
    'Email':'',
    'AccessChange':[],
    'CosdID': '',
    'filePath' : ''
    }

def closeWindow():
    data['PersonnelStatus']: PSselection
    data['RequestType']: RTselection
    data['EmployeeName']:ENentry
    data['EmployeeID']:EIDentry
    data['EmployeeType']:ETselection
    data['OrganizationName']:ONentry
    data['RequestedFor']:RFentry
    data['Email']:EMentry
    data['AccessChange']:ACselection
    data['CosdID']: cosdIDentry
    data['filePath']: filePath
        
    with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(data,file)
    root.destroy()

# autoFillButton
boldFont = font.Font(family="Inherit", size=12, weight="bold")
autoFillButton = Button(root, text="Auto Fill", command=closeWindow, padx=50, pady=10, bg='#428bca', highlightbackground="#428bca", 
                        fg='white', font= boldFont, relief=tk.FLAT)
autoFillButton.grid(row=13, column=1, sticky="w")

# Main Loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have already used a global variable `filePath` to store the selected filename, so what is your problem actually?

Comment: Please try to make a smaller [mcve]. If  your question is about clicking a button to get a file path, the actual contents of the form or file is irrelevant. You can use a single entry widget for that.

Comment: I am unable to access filePath though pickle after I close the userform.

Comment: Note that `data['filePath']: filePath` does not update the dictionary, use `data['filePath'] = filePath` instead.  Also there is no code on loading the pickle file, so it is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Why does Autofill destroy windows when I click? It doesn't fill up

Comment: line 156, in FLfunction
    fileLabel = fileLabel.get()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'get'. Did you mean: 'cget'? What does it do?

Comment: Thank you for all who contributed. The issue was with the print statement further down the code(not listed). I must be using it wrong since Print(data) does not return any values, but the variables are stored in pickle(also not listed).